# Where is the winston log files when using docker

Tags: node.js, linux, docker, winston

I am using winston for log and it's perfectly works when I start the nodejs app,

But my problem is I can not see logs when using docker.

where is the location of logs when using docker in linux?

the Logger.ts file:

```
import "express-async-errors";
import { createLogger, transports, format } from "Winston";
import fs from "fs";
import DailyRotateFile from "winston-daily-rotate-file";
import { environment, logDirectory } from "../config";
import path from "path";

let dir = logDirectory;
if (!dir) dir = path.resolve("logs");

// create directory if it is not present
if (!fs.existsSync(dir)) {
  fs.mkdirSync(dir);
}

const logLevel = environment === "development" ? "debug" : "warn";

const options = {
  file: {
    level: logLevel,
    filename: dir + "/%DATE%.log",
    datePattern: "YYYY-MM-DD",
    zippedArchive: true,
    timestamp: true,
    handleExceptions: true,
    humanReadableUnhandledException: true,
    prettyPrint: true,
    json: true,
    maxSize: "20m",
    colorize: true,
    maxFiles: "14d",
  },
};

export default createLogger({
 transports: [
   new transports.Console({
     level: logLevel,
     format: format.combine(
       format.errors({ stack: true }),
       format.prettyPrint()
      ),
    }),
    new DailyRotateFile(options.file),
  ],
   exceptionHandlers: [new DailyRotateFile(options.file)],
   exitOnError: false, // do not exit on handled exceptions
});
```

Comment: Can you please share your winston logger configuration?

Comment: the logger configuration id ok, and I found it inside the docker container. thanks @AssaelAzran

Comment: Ok. I wanted to make sure you are writing to console(stdout) and not to a file.

Comment: ok man, I've added my logger settup file to the question,  and I am writing logs in the file and also in development mode, I am showing in the console, but when running docker in -d mode the console is not accecible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's inside the container, in a directory space that's not usually directly accessible from the host.

You've also configured Winston to use a console transport, and those logs will go to the process's stdout.  This is useful since that's where Docker usually expects logs to go, and you can retrieve them using `docker logs` (or in production a log collector built on its setup).  A reasonable setup in Docker is to only use the console transport, not a file logger, and use `docker logs` to see what your process is up to.

The other thing you can do, if you want to keep the file logger, is to [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) a directory to collect the logs.  You'd do this when you run the container.  If your image installs the application code in `/app`, you'd add an option like

```
docker run -v $PWD/logs:/app/logs ...
```

(Note that there are potential permission issues writing to this directory if your application does not run as the root user, and this will be harder to manage in a cluster environment like Docker Swarm or Kubernetes.)

Comment: thanks man,  so inorder to persist my file logs you used -v command to save them in /app/logs . am I right ?  @DavidMaze

Comment: The `-v` option mounts the `logs` subdirectory of the current host directory on to `/app/logs` in the container, and then the file logger writes them there.

Comment: great,  I am using docker-compose, so in order to achieve this, I have to  set this option in my docker-compose file? @DavidMaze

Answer (score 0):

it's located inside the container, so after running the container,

you have to go to inside the container to see logs if the location is in project directory

```
docker exec -it <container id> /bin/bash
```

Answer (score 0):

Your log file will be created inside the container. let's say your app's root dir is `/app/src` then if you gave something like

```
new transports.File({ 
            filename: 'logs/app.log', 
            level: 'info', 
            maxsize: MAX_FILE_SIZE * 1024 * 1024,
            maxFiles: MAX_NUM_FILES,
            tailable: true 
        })
```

then logs will be present in `app/src/logs/app.log`.
You can verify it using `docker exec -it <container_id> sh`.

Now let's say you want to bind it so that you have access to `app.log` outside the container.

Assuming you have a `docker-compose.yml` file, you'll need to set up a volume in the following way:

```
volumes:
    - /home/<user_name>/logs:/app/src/logs # These need to be absolute paths to your directories
```

and also ensure that you have a `logs` directory created in `/home/<user_name>` directory.

When you spin up your container, your log file should be visible in `/home/<user_name>/logs` which will be in sync with the one inside your container.